# DB2 Connection String in IBM iSeries/AS 400

Tags: db2, connection-string, oledb, db2-400

I tried searching in the internet for the right connection string for this DB2. Just wanted to know if anyone is familiar with this. Below are the details of the database I want to connect to.

```
Driver   :  DB2 iSeries/AS 400
JDBC URL :  jdbc:as400://eagle1.eaglegl.com/EAFEDPRDDF/
Host     :  eagle1.eaglegl.com/EAFEDPRDDF/
Username :  *****
Password :  *****
```

Thank you.

Comment: lots of examples on the web

Comment: connectionstrings.com has been around since last century @Dennis

Comment: I didn't see any that's why I asked here. The problem is I'm trying to enter a command in Automation Anywhere where the bot will have to connect to this database. When I try to set up the command, it's asking me to set it up as Microsoft OLE DB for ODBC drivers however, I tried all examples of connection strings I found (yes, even in connectionstrings.com). Thank you guys for the very helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may perhaps be that you do not have a DB2 on i OLE DB driver installed.

Depending on which of the two 'standard' IBM i clients your organisation uses, have a look at either:

IBM i Access for Windows: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaik/rzaikoledbprovider.htm
(you'll need to change version to the correct one for your system)

or:

IBM i Access Client Solutions :
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1022156

P.S. the 'as400' moniker is specifically for jdbc connections using the IBM i Java Toolbox.

Comment: I was able to figure it out and this was exactly the solution - thank you!